# NodeJS how to find all XML nodes by element

Tags: xml, node.js

I have an XML similar to

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b>test1</b>
    <c>
      <b>test2</b>
      <b>test3</b>
    </c>
  </a>
  <b>test4</b>
</root>
```

And I want to retrieve an array containing all the values of `<b>` elements:

```
expectedOutput = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
```

What would be the best NodeJS library and how to use it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I came up with the following code, let me know if someone knows a better way:

```
var DOMParser = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser;

var xml = getXML();
var document = DOMParser.parseFromString(xml);
var spans = findElements('span', document.documentElement);
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    console.dir(spans[i]);
}

function findElements(element, xml) {
    var output = [];

    var nodes = xml.childNodes;
    if (nodes != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].nodeName == element && nodes[i].childNodes.length == 1) {
                output.push(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            } else {
                output = output.concat(findElements(element, nodes[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

This allows me to retrieve the values of all the element of type `<span>`